# UWP System.Runtime.Interop.COMException on Debug but System.Exception on Release

Tags: c#, uwp, winrt-httpclient

I am facing the following problem

My solution is setup using MVVM like this.

- A UWP app -> View
- A PCL targeting Windows Universal and .NET Framework 4.6 -> ViewModel
- A PCL targeting Windows Universal and .NET Framework 4.6 -> Model

In the View Project I have a service that makes web calls using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`. this service is injected into several ViewModels.

In a view model I have a try catch block like this.

```
try
{

    await webClientService.MakeACallAsync();

}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
{
    //web exceptions such as 404, 401, 500 etc
    // code handling exceptions.
}
```

The MakeACallAsync is this function, but the problem is not limited to this call only, it happens with other calls like it as well.

```
public async Task<string> MakeACallAsync(string username, string password)
        {                
            var usernamepassword = $"{username}:{password}";
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(usernamepassword);
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Basic", base64);
            return await httpClient.GetStringAsync( a uri here );
        }
```

Now in case the service throws any exceptions because of a 404, 500, etc response I catch these exceptions and handle them.

This works well in Debug, but in Release the exceptions are not thrown as `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` but as `System.Exception`.

Does anybody know why that happens??

Comment: Please explain the downvote and suggest a way to improve the question.

Comment: We cannot see the code for `webClientService.MakeACallAsync()`. Trying to answer a question without access to all relevant information is going to result in guesswork. Not a convincing reason to downvote, to me, but others may feel different.

Comment: edited the question to provide the code for MakeACallAsync

Comment: How did you get the Exception `System.Exception`?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT First I got some crashes from HockeyApp where I had uploaded the release version for testing with descriptions like 

Reason: 
Internal server error (500). Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

And thought "well I was handling those"
Then I placed some breakpoints while running the app in relase mode and saw the problem.

Comment: Could you please post the exception messages of `System.Exception` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I'm experiencing the same issue. The exceptions are wrapped exceptions internally thrown by a web client when the connection to server is lost etc. I'm targeting Android and iOS and I can't find a way to make `COMException` visible in my project at all.

Comment: @Corcus - Were you able to resolve this issue? In addition to the System.Exception firing, we are also getting the following: `System.ArgumentNullException in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`. Despite us handling the System.Exception and the method safely exiting, the ArgumentNullException seems to propogate further up the call stack, causing other methods to fail with unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @nicovanvuuren No unfortunately I haven't figured this out. I haven't experienced the ArgumentNullException though.